# How can I make my index function faster?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, struct, cell

So given an struct array, Index with fields, Word, Documents, Locations, it takes a cell array of char arrays and indexes it into Index and also records the DocNums of documents that index appears in.

```
function Index = InsertDoc(Index, newDoc, DocNum)
    for i = 1:numel(newDoc) 
        contains = any(strcmpi(newDoc(i),[Index.Word]));
        if any(contains);
            curr = find(strcmpi(newDoc(i),[Index.Word]),true);
            Index(curr).Documents{1} = unique([Index(curr).Documents{1},DocNum]);
            if (numel(Index(curr).Documents{1}) ~= numel(Index(curr).Locations))
                Index(curr).Locations{end+1} = [i];
            else
                Index(curr).Locations{end} = [Index(curr).Locations{end},i];
            end

        else 
            curr = numel(Index) + 1;
            Index(curr).Word = [newDoc(i)];
            Index(curr).Documents = {DocNum};
            Index(curr).Locations = {[i]};
        end
    end
end
```

For example

```
Doc1 = {'Matlab', 'is', 'awesome'};
Doc2 = {'Programming', 'is', 'very', 'very', 'fun'};
Doc3 = {'I', 'love', 'Matlab','very','much};

someIndex = InitializeIndex;
% InitializeIndex just creates struct array with the given fields and empty cell arrays
someIndex = InsertDoc(someIndex, Doc1, 1);
someIndex = InsertDoc(someIndex, Doc2, 2);
someIndex = InsertDoc(someIndex, Doc3, 3);
```

The result would be for
someIndex(1)

```
Word: 'Matlab'
Documents: [1 3]
Locations: {[1] [3]}
```

someIndex(2)

```
Word: 'is'
Documents: [1 2]
Locations: {[2] [2]}
```

someIndex(5)

```
Word: 'very'
Documents: [2 3]
Locations: {[3 4] [4]}
```

I need to be able to run this with a struct array of 20000 elements with a variety of words, and right now it takes and absurd amount of time to finish indexing. How can I improve this algorithm?

Comment: Use the inbuilt profiler to determine what functions are taking the most time; then you'll know which parts of the code to target.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [allocate memory](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocate-memory-for-a-cell-array.html) for your cell array "*Index*" before your loop starts.